# Scrolling through tabs is very slow on Firefox - React JS - Ant Design Tab

Tags: reactjs, scroll, antd

I am experiencing an issue where scrolling through a list of tabs on Firefox is very slow in comparison to other browsers. I found the issue using Ant Design's tab component, so I'm unsure if it's specific to Ant Design tabs or not.

A similar question was asked here: [Javascript workaround for slow scrolling with smooth scrolling in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24786274/4220762) however turning off smooth scrolling does not change the behavior.

I've tried it on other browsers and it seems to scroll fine, but on Firefox it scrolls very slowly.
There is an example on Ant Design's website where you can see the issue:
[Tabs component example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6y1bg?file=/index.js).

Firefox behavior:
[image]

Chrome behavior:
[image]

Edge behavior:
[image]

Is there anything that can be done about this or am I doomed to have slow scrolling tabs on Firefox? I've looked online to no avail. Note: I am using the latest Firefox (86.0).