# Disable Firefox smooth scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

Im wondering, is there a way to disable Firefox and Edge smooth scroll, and make it just like in Chrome? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996067/turn-off-firefoxs-smooth-scrolling), but it's just for logging.

Comment: Same as this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786274/javascript-workaround-for-slow-scrolling-with-smooth-scrolling-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have been using https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel plugin to do this.

I had to add `overflow: hidden` to `body` and listener for `mousewheel` event.

I don't know if it works with Edge, as I don't have Win10 installed, but it works with Firefox. You can also animate scrolling in all browsers this way using `$.animate()`.

Demo: http://codepen.io/Shawo/pen/JGqvGr

Comment: but then i cant use arrows, pgup/down, and scroll by clicking mouse wheel.

Comment: I've tried to add keyboard support and I've found out in Firefox it's not possible to make a non-smooth scroll outside `mousewheel` event handler. Check the demo code - even if the code should work, it triggers smooth scrolling, at least on my PC. Middle-click is possible to implement (using `click` event) but it will require some coding. Also, adding touch scrolling should be a priority.